# I can't get my function to move my image by clicking "a"

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I am trying to make it so when I click a or A it will move my image to a different location. I am purely coding this off of snips of code I found on the internet and I am probably doing something very wrong.

```js
function move1() {
    document.getElementById("character").style.right=450px;
}

var KeypressFunctions = [];
KeypressFunctions['A'.charCodeAt(0)] = move1
KeypressFunctions['a'.charCodeAt(0)] = move1
```

```css
h1 {
    width: 300px;
    margin:400px auto;
    color: red;
    font-family:Impact ;
}
#character {
    width:45px; 
    height:45px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:100px;
    right:800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainc.css">
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            So I am just testing out stuff on here 
        </h1>
        <img src="C:/Users/Nick Malone/Desktop/Downloads/block.jpg" id="character">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting margin Insted of using right

Comment: I haven't tried that yet Ashish, how exactly do I do this?

Comment: Just use ```document.getElementById("character").style.marginRight=450px;```

Comment: `move1` is never called.  What is the purpose of `KeypressFunctions` it is never used.

Comment: Richard, I don't know really how to do this got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple `click` event function in `jquery`. It will move the image from left to right.

```js
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    $('.movingimg').css('margin-left','450px');
});
```

```css
img{ display: block; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <a href="#" class="clickme">Click me!</a>
<img class="movingimg" src="https://s26.postimg.org/ma8qknfw5/image.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard CSS enables the animation for you. Best way to trigger it is by using `classList` to toggle the CSS Class with the motion rules on and off the car.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var car = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  car.classList.toggle("activate");
});
```

```css
button {
  min-width: 48px;
}

img {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.activate {
  transform: translate(3em, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(3em, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(3em, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(3em, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(3em, 0);
}
```

```html
<button>A</button>
<div><img src="https://intrest.run/media/car.svg"></div>
```